# Snowflake PARSE_XML normalizes attributes?

Tags: xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```sql
select  select PARSE_XML('<X A9="ZZ"A1="YY"/>')
```

returns

```xml
<X A1="YY" A9="ZZ"></X>
```

It appears that PARSE_XML has normailized (re-ordered) the attributes. While this is not 'wrong' (XML defines attributes an an unordered collection of name/value pairs) it is annoying, especially if you are trying to compare the inserted value with the original value, as is screws up text or checksum based comparissons (I know any attempt to treat XML as a string will end in tears)....

Is there any way to preserve attribute ordering with snowflake.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be no way of preventing attribute reordering in `PARSE_XML()`.
The same goes for JSON dictionaries and `PARSE_JSON()`, there are no ordered dictionaries.